# CMP и SUB, почему CF=1?

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте!

есть такой пример:

```
mov al, 01
cmp al, 02 или sub al, 02
```

складываем:
0000 0001b
1111 1110b (*двоичное дополнение 02*)
---------------
 **1111 1111**b (*результат 00FFh или -01*)

Вопрос -> почему устанавливается бит переноса CF=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае, упрощённо говоря, у вас произошло переполнение в момент обращения числа `02`. Математически, отрицательное число содержит бесконечное число лидирующих единиц, так же как положительное - бесконечное число лидирующих нулей. А вы оставили только 8 знаков вместо бесконечного их числа. Здесь и возникает переполнение, которое удобнее представлять себе как заём из старшего разряда. Так и будет всегда, когда вычитаешь из меньшего числа большее.

Comment: Странно это, так как бесконечное число n1110 и n0001 взаимно компенсируют друг друга, ничего не выпадает. Иначе, если -02 представить как FEh + 01h = FFh, ничего не переполняется. При обратном действии -01 (FFh) + 02h = 01h, тут действительно есть перенос и это вполне обосновано.

Comment: @TESTer, операция `neg`, которая делает из положительного отрицательное и наоборот, устанавливает `CF=1`, если операнд не равен нулю. Так что и здесь это удобное правило остаётся справедливым. Не забывайте, что я всего лишь описал удобное для запоминание правило, если вы хотите понять истинную логику инструкций `x86`, вам нужно читать их мануал, он есть на официальном сайте Intel.

Comment: Да, действительно, при операции neg выставляется флаг, я уже также подумал в этом направлении, что это операция происходит не явно. Спасибо!